# Custom Triggers and Bindings for Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, triggers, azure-functions, azureservicebus

We would like our Azure function to use Custom Trigger binding so if we want to change from Service Bus Trigger to HttpTrigger than we should be able to do it easily with some configuration / app settings change rather than a code change. Is there a way that we can write a custom trigger class implementation. We are currently using .Net core 3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible by implementing `ITriggerBinding`, but with some serious disadvantages: there is no support for custom activation / scaling logic when running on a consumption plan. ([source](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1154#issuecomment-1009166597)). There are some ideas about how support for custom triggers could be added that would run in the Functions Premium plan. The reason it would depend on the premium plan is that there is always at least one VM assigned to the plan, and it could run your activation/scaling logic. ([source](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1154#issuecomment-736905558)).

If you still want to go ahead, [here](https://krvarma.medium.com/custom-extension-for-azure-functions-part-1-triggers-e88e4bc94669) is a blogpost outlining the steps involved. It is rather dated so you might need to change some things here and there.

Comment: Thanks this helps. I looked at the article and yeah it seems that it will work fine for premium plan but not for consumption plan and our Azure functions are premium plan.  Will go through the link for implementation.